# Which polynomial level sets are bounded?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}^n&=\left\{p:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}, (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}} a_{i_1\cdots i_k}x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}\;\bigg|\; a_{i_1\cdots i_n}\in\mathbb{R}\text{ almost all zero}\right\}, \\
\mathcal{L}^n&=\{p^{-1}(\{0\}):p\in\mathcal{P}^n\}.
\end{align}$$
For example
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:x^2+y^2+z^2=1\},\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=z^2\}\in\mathcal{L}^3.$$

> **Question:** What conditions on the coefficients of $p\in\mathcal{P}^n$ ensures that $p^{-1}(\{0\})$ is **bounded**?

Answer (score 3):

In the plane, an algebraic curve whose term of highest degree has odd degree in $x$ or $y$ is unbounded, because every real polynomial of odd degree has a real root.

Comment: See also the last paragraph of http://math.stackexchange.com/a/740905/.