# Help with proof that that affine plane curves in $\mathbb{C}^2$ are not compact

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-curves

This is a problem from Kirwan's *Complex Algebraic Curves* that I'm stuck on. She gives a hint suggesting that for $C = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2: P(x,y) = 0\}$, show that at all but finitely many points $a\in\mathbb{C}$ there is a $b$ such that that $P(a,b) = 0$. I know appealing to the Heine-Borel theorem finishes the argument if I can show the hint. It's also pretty obvious that if $g(y) = P(a,y)$ is non-constant, then we can factorize $g$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and let $b$ be one of the roots to conclude. I don't understand why we can do this at all but finitely many $a$ though.

It seems like having $g(y) = k_a$ where $k_a\in\mathbb{C}$ for infinitely many $a\in \mathbb{C}$ *should* give some kind of contradiction. It would be easy if it were the same constant $k_a$ every time, since we could factorize $g(y) - k_a$ as a polynomial of $a$ to show that the number of $a$'s where this occurs is bounded by the polynomial degree. But $k_a$ should vary with $a$, right? Do I need to appeal to some kind of complex-analytic argument?

I might just be missing something obvious. Any help explaining this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First write

$$P(x, y) = p_n(x) y^n + p_{n-1} (x) y^{n-1} + \cdots + p_1(x) y + p_0(x).$$

Fix $a \in \mathbb  C$. Then if $g_a(y) =P(a, y)$ is constant, we have

$$p_n(a) = p_{n-1}(a) = \cdots = p_1(a) = 0$$

Note that there are only finitely many $a\in \mathbb C$ which satisfies this conditions.

Answer (score 0):

We show that $C \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ is not bounded. Assume that it is, then there is a constant $M > 0$ such that $C \subset B(0, M)$, where the open ball is$$B(0, M) = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : \left|x\right|^2 + |y|^2 < M\}.$$Let $y_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|y_0| > M$ and $g = f(\,\cdot\,,y_0)$ is a nonconstant polynomial. By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $g$ has a root $x_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and the point $(x_0, y_0) \in C$. This is a contradiction, as $(x_0, y_0) \notin B(0, M)$.

Also, this question appears to have been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461400/compactness-of-algebraic-curves-over-mathbb-c2?rq=1).